# What use is the method resolution order table in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, method-resolution-order

```
>>> O = object
>>> class F(O): pass
>>> class E(O): pass
>>> class D(O): pass
>>> class C(D,F): pass
>>> class B(D,E): pass
>>> class A(B,C): pass
```

Below is the MRO table of these classes.

```
                          6
                         ---
Level 3                 | O |                  (more general)
                      /  ---  \
                     /    |    \                      |
                    /     |     \                     |
                   /      |      \                    |
                  ---    ---    ---                   |
Level 2        3 | D | 4| E |  | F | 5                |
                  ---    ---    ---                   |
                   \  \ _ /       |                   |
                    \    / \ _    |                   |
                     \  /      \  |                   |
                      ---      ---                    |
Level 1            1 | B |    | C | 2                 |
                      ---      ---                    |
                        \      /                      |
                         \    /                      \ /
                           ---
Level 0                 0 | A |                (more specialized)
                           ---
```

What does this table do for us? After all, Python considers the order specified in `__mro__`, not according to this table.

Comment: This "table" is a directed acyclic graph (DAG) that models the inheritance hierarchy of `A`. The MRO of A is *derived* from the DAG via the C3 linearization algorithm.

Comment: The table itself is a partial order; the MRO is one possible *total* order based on it.

Comment: The graph shown (presumably taken from [here](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)) is just a visual representation of the code snippet above. I am not sure what your question is really asking...?

Answer (score 1):

Your table is a directed acyclic graph (DAG) that represents the inheritance hierarchy of `A` (assuming edges point from a class to a parent class). As a DAG, it implies a [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) of the classes involved. For example, `A` "precedes" both `B` and `C`, but the graph says nothing about whether `B` precedes `C` or `C` precedes `B`. In fact, neither is true.

The MRO of a class is a [*total* order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) derived from the DAG, generated by the [C3 linearization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization). Given any two classes, we can say that one precedes the other, according to two simple rules:

1. A class always precedes any of its parent classes
2. The order of base class is respected. (For example, `A` inherits from `B` and `C`, in that order, so `B` precedes `C`.)

In this relatively simple example, it appears that the total order is just a breadth-first traversal of the graph, but that's not true in general. The graph itself imposes no particular "horizontal" ordering of `D`, `E`, and `F`; it's just been drawn to correspond to the MRO.